# Taylor series [a = x]

Tags: taylor-expansion

I have a function u(r) and a = $r_0$ = r

Basically, my Taylor serie should looks like

$$u(r_0) + \frac{d}{dr}U(r_0)(r-r_0) + \frac{1}{2} \frac{d^2}{dr^2} U(r_0) (r-r_0)^2$$

If $r = r_0$ then everything is = 0, exept$u(r_0)$

However, I don't know why in my book they the answer is

$$u(r_0) + \frac{d}{dr}U(r_0) + \frac{1}{2} \frac{d^2}{dr^2} U(r_0)$$

I'm would like to know if I'm correct.